# nirq: Flags mismatch irq 80. 00002083 (ledtrig-gpio) vs. 00000083 (USER)

Tags: c++, arm, embedded-linux, gpio, sysfs

I am doing some experiments on SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK1 board. I am using Linux operating system. I am exploiting GPIOS of my board. There is **RED LED** defined at **GPIO 10** and **USER button** defined at **GPIO 29**. I wrote C++ program to control LED of the board and here is the code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

#define LED0_PATH "/sys/class/leds/red"

void removeTrigger(){
   // remove the trigger from the LED
   std::fstream fs;
   fs.open( LED0_PATH "/trigger", std::fstream::out);
   fs << "none";
   fs.close();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   if(argc!=2){
 cout << "Usage is makeLED and one of: on, off, flash or status"
<< endl;
 cout << "e.g. makeLED flash" << endl;
   }

   string cmd(argv[1]);
   std::fstream fs;
   cout << "Starting the LED flash program" << endl;
   cout << "The LED Path is: " << LED0_PATH << endl;


 // select whether it is on, off or flash
   if(cmd=="on"){
 removeTrigger();
 fs.open (LED0_PATH "/brightness", std::fstream::out);
 fs << "1";
 fs.close();
   }

   else if (cmd=="off"){
 removeTrigger();
 fs.open (LED0_PATH "/brightness", std::fstream::out);
 fs << "0";
 fs.close();
   }

   else if (cmd=="flash"){
 fs.open (LED0_PATH "/trigger", std::fstream::out);
 fs << "timer";
 fs.close();
 fs.open (LED0_PATH "/delay_on", std::fstream::out);
 fs << "50";
 fs.close();
 fs.open (LED0_PATH "/delay_off", std::fstream::out);
 fs << "50";
 fs.close();
   }

   else if (cmd=="status"){
 // display the current trigger details
 fs.open( LED0_PATH "/trigger", std::fstream::in);
 string line;
 while(getline(fs,line)) cout << line;
 fs.close();
 }

   else{
 cout << "Invalid command" << endl;
 }

cout << "Finished the LED flash program" << endl;
       return 0;
```

This seems to work fine : When I tape `./target_bin off` the Red Led turn off and the same for `on` and `flash` commands.

But when I tried to control LED ( RED / GPIO 10 ) with BUTTON ( USER / GPIO 29 ) I added this part of code :

```
else if (cmd=="button"){
        removeTrigger();
        fs.open (LED0_PATH "/trigger", std::fstream::out);
        fs << "gpio";
        fs.close();
        fs.open (LED0_PATH "/gpio", std::fstream::out);
        fs << "29";
        fs.close();
   }
```

And now when I tape `./target_bin button` It shows me an error :

> nirq: Flags mismatch irq 80. 00002083 (ledtrig-gpio) vs. 00000083
>   (USER) leds red: request_irq failed with error -16

Can Anyone help me out please ?

Comment: You still have IRQ requested by LED trigger. Read binding documentation how to free the GPIO line of the LED GPIO trigger. Better approach is to disable LED on this GPIO line in DTS.

Comment: I prefer to not modify the DTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And now when I tape [sic] ./target_bin button It shows me an error :
>
> > nirq: Flags mismatch irq 80. 00002083 (ledtrig-gpio) vs. 00000083 (USER) leds red: request_irq failed with error -16

Error 16 is "Device or resource busy".
The device or resource in question is the gpio_key for the push button.
Note that the error message mentions "USER", which happens to be the `label` assigned to the gpio_key for the push button in the Device Tree file [**at91-sama5d27_som1_ek.dts**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623941/where-can-i-find-the-mapping-of-sama5d27-som1-ek1-devices-and-its-gpios/57631678#57631678).

```
gpio_keys {
    ...
    pb4 {
        label = "USER";
        gpios = <&pioA PIN_PA29 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        ...
    };
};
```

In order for GPIO 29 to be used as a LED trigger, it must be an available, i.e. unused, GPIO.
However the default **dts** file configures that GPIO 29 to be a gpio_key, and therefore that GPIO is owned by the gpio_key driver.
GPIO 29 is not an unused pin, and is not available for use as a LED trigger (i.e. ownership cannot be transferred to the ledtrig-gpio driver).

You can either use the push-button gpio_key as an [input-event device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173044/linux-kernel-event-timeval-or-timespec/57176062#57176062) as currently configured, or reconfigure the GPIO 29 so that it is not a gpio_key and available for use as a LED trigger.

---

**ADDENDUM**
[responses to comments]

> But when i search for the devices which are " USED " on my board with gpioinfo | grep "[used]" command I find that RED led is used before I run my program : line 10: "PA10" "red" output active-high [used] but my code does not show an error for it.

Are you complaining that you did not get a LED error?
I fail to understand what point you are trying to make.

> Why would it show an error for BUTTON ...

As I already explained the **dts** file configures GPIO 29 (i.e. the push button) to be a **gpio_key**, and assigning GPIO 29 to be a **LED trigger** causes a conflict.

To be more specific, the LED trigger driver (ledtrig-gpio) requires that the interrupt be configured for "one-shot" mode.

```
 * IRQF_ONESHOT - Interrupt is not reenabled after the hardirq handler finished.
 *                Used by threaded interrupts which need to keep the
 *                irq line disabled until the threaded handler has been run.
 ...
#define IRQF_ONESHOT        0x00002000
```

This (new) interrupt mode (i.e. 0x00002083) conflicts with the existing mode/flags (i.e. 0x00000083) established by the gpio_keys driver.
This conflict means that this GPIO cannot be used simultaneously for both a gpio_key (input event) and a LED trigger.
Therefore you have to choose in which mode this GPIO will operate.

> ... and not for LED ?

You mean you want the error to occur on the LED?
You don't get to choose which device causes an error when you perform a specific operation.

The operation you requested, i.e. assign a specific GPIO (which is already installed as a **gpio_key**) to be the LED trigger, failed during the assignment of the (new) interrupt handler for the gpio_key.
So the error is reported for the gpio_key, and not the LED.

---

For further confirmation to quell your doubts:
Since the error message mentions *"irq 80"*, you should look up this *"irq 80"* in the **/proc/interrupts** file on your board.
That file should indicate that *"irq 80"* is associated with "GPIO 29" (which per the DT is a gpio_key).

For yet another procedure to quell your doubts:
Locate an unused PIO pin that is accessible and unused (by any peripheral or any driver/process as a gpio).
Assign that pin as the LED trigger.
No error should occur (assuming you selected an unused pin).
Short the pin to ground or VDD_3V3 to change the (default) state of the LED.

---

> How can I reconfigure the button USER so that it is not a gpio_key and be available for use as a LED trigger ?

As I already wrote, the Device Tree file **at91-sama5d27_som1_ek.dts** is where the GPIO with the push button is declared to be a gpio_key, and I also posted a snippet of the salient lines of that node.
If you do not want that GPIO to be configured as a gpio_key, then the Device Tree file needs to be modified by removing that node (and of course recompiled into a **dtb**).

Comment: But when i search for the devices which are " USED " on my board with `gpioinfo | grep "\[used\]"` command I find that RED led is used before I run my program : `line  10:       "PA10"        "red"  output  active-high [used]` but my code does not show an error for it. Why would it show an error for BUTTON and not for LED ?

Comment: How can I reconfigure the button USER so that it is not a gpio_key and be available for use as a LED trigger ?